# Some properties are missed in Get Properties endpoint

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Dears,

Please let me know, why are some properties missed in response of (GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties) endpoint. For example, I have Windows family in my Revit file that have Constraints and Phasing categories in its property's list but after calling mentioned endpoint, I cannot find these categories in related JSON response while in A360 I can see these categories.
Thank you in ADV.

[image: Endpoint Response]

[image: A360 - Windows - properties]

Comment: from the image it seems you're using the sample model (that come as part of A360 account), right? some of those models are actually strange and may return wrong data (they are there just for showing some features). I would recommend trying with a better model, like https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html (upload to your account).

Comment: Dear Augusto, you are right the issue was related to that model. But I don't know why is different result of a360's UI and forge APIs in this case?

Comment: these specific models are basic samples on A360, but they are not full files, just a reference, therefore good only for UI demonstration.